# Why doesn't my dictionary grow?

Tags: python, dictionary, fabric

### Edit:

I've updated my code below to reflect the full file, as requested.

---

I'm using fabric to do some work:

```
#! /usr/bin/python25
import os
import subprocess
import ConfigParser

from fabric.api import env, execute, parallel, \
                       run, runs_once, task

# --- sudo consts --- #
# relative path, regardless of where we're executing from
RELATIVE_PATH = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
BASE_SERVER_FILE = os.path.join(RELATIVE_PATH, 'cfg', 'veri.serv.cfg')
BASE_CONFIG_FILE = os.path.join(RELATIVE_PATH, 'cfg', 'veri.base.cfg')
# --- end consts --- #

# --- globals because why not --- #
# did we specify a server override file?
subServSpecified = False

# dict of host objects
hostObjs = {}
# --- end globals --- #

@task
def SetHosts(hostlist):
    env.hosts = list(hostlist)

@task
@parallel
def DoWork(cmd):
    hostObjs[env.host].cmdResults[cmd] = run(cmd)
    print env.host
    print cmd
    print hostObjs[env.host].cmdResults.items()
    print len(hostObjs[env.host].cmdResults)
    print "*" * 50

class Host:
    fqdn = ''

    # dict {'command string': 'result string'}
    cmdResults = {}
    desiredResults = []    

    def __init__(self, fqdn):
        self.fqdn = fqdn
        hostObjs[self.fqdn] = self

def CreateHosts(servlist, commands, desiredResults):
    for serv in servlist:
        h = Host(serv)
        h.desiredResults = list(desiredResults)

baseConfigParser = ConfigParser.SafeConfigParser()
baseConfigParser.read(BASE_CONFIG_FILE)
runlist = baseConfigParser.get('Config List', 'runlist').strip().split("\n")
print runlist

baseServConfigParser = ConfigParser.SafeConfigParser()
baseServConfigParser.read(BASE_SERVER_FILE)
servlist = baseServConfigParser.get('Server List', 'servers').strip().split("\n")
print servlist

for subDir in runlist:
    print subDir
    relativeRunPath = os.path.join(RELATIVE_PATH, 'cfg', subDir)
    subConfigParser = ConfigParser.SafeConfigParser()
    subConfigParser.read(os.path.join(relativeRunPath, 'veri.cfg'))
    commands = subConfigParser.get('Command List', 'commands').strip().split("\n")
    if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(relativeRunPath, 'veri.serv.cfg')):
        subServSpecified = True
        subServConfigParser = ConfigParser.SafeConfigParser()
        subServConfigParser.read(os.path.join(relativeRunPath, 'veri.serv.cfg'))
        subServList = subServConfigParser.get('Server List', 'servers').strip().split("\n")
    else:
        subServList = servlist

    CreateHosts(subServList, commands, "succeeded!")
    execute(SetHosts, subServList)

    for cmd in commands:
        execute(DoWork, cmd)
```

I can see that my `cmdResults` dictionary isn't actually growing in size:

```
my.serv.com
nc -zw1 another.serv.com 9988 | gawk '{print $7}'
[("nc -zw1 another.serv.com 9988 | gawk '{print $7}'", 'succeeded!')]
1
**************************************************
my.serv.com
nc -zw1 another.serv.com 8050 | gawk '{print $7}'
[("nc -zw1 another.serv.com 8050 | gawk '{print $7}'", 'succeeded!')]
1
**************************************************
my.serv.com
nc -zw1 another.serv.com 80 | gawk '{print $7}'
[("nc -zw1 another.serv.com 80 | gawk '{print $7}'", 'succeeded!')]
1
**************************************************
```

The **1** above appears on every iteration of the loop, and the printout of `items()` is always just the single entry. Can anyone see what I'm missing here?

### Example Input Files:

```
//veri.cfg
[Command List]
commands:
; T
    nc -zw1 another.serv.com 9988 | gawk '{print $7}'

; P
    nc -zw1 another.serv.com 8050 | gawk '{print $7}'

; G
    nc -zw1 another.serv.com 80 | gawk '{print $7}'

//veri.serv.cfg
[Server List]
servers: 
    my.serv.com
    my.serv2.com

//veri.base.cfg
[Config List]
runlist:
    veri.acl
```

### Directory Structure:

```
root
 -/cfg (veri.serv.cfg / veri.base.cfg)
 -/cfg/veri.acl (veri.cfg)
 -script.py
```

Comment: Suggest you make as small a *complete* program as you can and edit your question to show that.  This one is incomplete: somebody reading this cannot run it for themselves and see the output that you see.

Comment: Yeah, the complete `fabfile` would be helpful here.

Comment: I've updated my question, though the `fab` portion is literally what I posted already. There is no `fabfile`; it's all direct API calls

Comment: Can you provide the content of `runlist` and of `commands` for each please?

Comment: More details updated

Comment: I'm not into this topic but maybe this quote from the docs helps you: "execute:(...)This technique works because tasks that themselves have no host list (this includes the global host list settings) only run one time. If used inside a “regular” task that is going to run on multiple hosts, calls to execute will also run multiple times, resulting in multiplicative numbers of subtask calls – be careful!

If you would like your execute calls to only be called once, you may use the runs_once decorator."
Seems like your function `DoWork` is executed multiple times that's why you see the same output.

Comment: Thanks @a_guest - unfortunately, that's kind of the point of the script. Run n-commands on n-hosts, in parallel (i.e., the actual commands should be sequential, but each host can run them in parallel). So, I'm not exactly seeing the same output - just that the dictionary isn't growing. I'll update my output to make that more clear.

Comment: Yeah, I see. But like this it seems that `DoWork` is executed with the same arguments multiple times. Maybe it would be wise to create a class `DoWork`, implement `__call__`, decorate it with `runs_once` and then do `hostObjs[env.host].cmdResults[cmd] = run(cmd)` within `DoWork.__call__`. For each command you would create a new instance and then do `execute(InstanceOfDoWork, cmd)`. Or you give `cmd` to `__init__` and do `self.cmd = cmd` and then within `__call__` you refer to `self.cmd`. I think the 2nd is better.